# Change size of EditText(any View) shown in alertBox?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to show an alertBox for user input. So I've added EditText View in alertBox. code of my alertBox is:

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            //input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            input.setX(10);
            android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Title")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setView(input)
                    .setTitle("Create new Playlist")
                    .setPositiveButton("CREATE",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // finish the current activity
                                    // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                                    playlistName = input.getText().toString();
                                    dialog.cancel();


                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // cancel the dialog box
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            android.app.AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

This gives following alert dialogue:

[image]

But EditText is not starting from where Title and Message of alert starts (not properly indented). So I want following type of EditText which has proper indentation in the alert dialogue.

[image]

How to do this? How to change position of views in alert dialogue? Or how to change size of view?

Comment: try using a custom view for that.

Comment: Can you please give an example ?

Comment: look at this Document : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1225/dialog/16252/custom-alert-dialog-with-edittext#t=201611080653420964273

Comment: @14bce109: set layout and margin for `input` View before passing it to setView

Comment: @14bce109, Check my answer for sample code

Comment: So many pirated songs! ahhahahhaha :P

Comment: lol all songs are pirated...:D @YakuZa

Comment: @YakuZa lol its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

XML Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextField"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
    LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

final EditText mEditText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextField);

dialogBuilder.setTitle("Title");
dialogBuilder.setMessage("Type your message here");

dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", null);
dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", null);

final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Button positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String enteredTextString= mEditText.getText().toString();
                //To whatever with the text entered
            }
        });
        Button negativeButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        negativeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

    }
});
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using a custom view...
define the EditText in a layout file, say, lay.xml

Then

```
builder.setMessage("Title")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setContentView(R.layout.lay);
```